# Why is a partial class template specialization on a matching template class ambiguous with another partial specialization without the template match?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

The question may be too hard to describe in on sentence in the title, but here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class U, class Enabler>
struct my_trait : std::false_type
{};

template <class T, class U>
struct my_trait<T, U, 
                std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value>> : std::true_type
{};

template <class T>
class temped
{};

template <class T>
struct my_trait<temped<T>, temped<T>, void> : std::false_type
{};

template <class T, class U>
using trait_t = my_trait<T, U, void>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << trait_t<int, float>::value << std::endl;   // false
    std::cout << trait_t<int, int>::value << std::endl;     // true

    // Compilation error: Ambiguous
    //std::cout << trait_t<temped<int>, temped<int>>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

([also available on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VE6ARX))

Basically, we have a base template class `my_trait` taking two types (and a dummy type for specialization purposes), with two partial specializations:

- When the two types are the same
- When the two types are instantiation of the `temped` class template for the same type

Naïvely, we would have expected the second partial specialization not to be ambiguous with the first, as it feels "more specialized", putting more restriction on the deduced types for `T` and `U` on the base template.
Yet major compilers seems to agree that we were wrong with our expectations: why is it not considered more specialized?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17412686/9171697

Answer (score 1):

@super's now-deleted answer got this basically right. `std::enable_if_t<...>` is not `void` in partial ordering; as a dependent type it can in principle be something completely arbitrary. It effectively is considered a completely unique type for partial ordering purposes.

As a result of this mismatch, the deduction during partial ordering fails in both directions, and the specializations are ambiguous.

Comment: But it's not really a dependent type when doing partial ordering, is it? It's `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<DummyT, DummyT>::value>` where `DummyT` is a theoretical-only "synthesized" but specific type ([\[temp.func.order\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.func.order#3)).

Comment: Maybe a "synthesized unique type" also implies that there might be additional specializations using that type, even if no currently visible specializations could make a difference? But does the Standard say that anywhere?

Comment: I may be missing your point: the `std_enable_if_t<>` provides a preferred partial specialization in the statement `trait_t<int, int>::value`, so it looks like it is considered 
 `void` (otherwise, it seems this expression should evaluate to false by selecting the base template). On the other hand, the statement `trait_t<temped<int>, temped<int>>::value` leads to an ambiguity, although the partial specialization `my_trait<temped<T>, temped<T>, void>` we hoped would be more specialized explicitly states the `void` type.

Comment: There is an open issue that is related to this one: http://wg21.link/CWG2160
However, in that case, deduction apparently does succeed in one direction (?) so I'm not able to reconcile that example with this one.

Comment: More compiler results that seem non-uniform: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394260/9171697

Comment: @KaenbyouRin indeed, if Bogdan's claim is true: that `P` is skipped when it's a non-deduced context and "success" is returned for that P/A pair (in Clang), then deduction should succeed here, in one direction. I don't understand why Clang would reject the code here.

Comment: And in any case, the "real" answer to OP's question should be: the standard is not clear on this, so don't write code like this until the standard clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

it's because

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<temped<int>, temped<int>>
```

resolves to void and then you have

```
my_trait<temped<int>, temped<int>, void>::value
```

defined ambigiously as true or false. If you change the type enable_if resolves to, let's say bool, everything compiles fine

Comment: The OP is asking why it is ambiguous, under the context of template specialization partial ordering. If you change to `std::enable_if_t<*, bool>`, then it kind of defeat the purpose (because it is not even enabled for specialization).