# Function template overloading difference

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I get different behavior when trying to overload function and function template. For function:

```
void foo(int)
{
    std::cout << "int";
}

void foo(char)
{
    std::cout << "char";
}
```

`foo(42)` is `int`. But for function template:

```
template <int T>
void bar()
{
    std::cout << "int T";
}

template <char T>
void bar()
{
    std::cout << "char T";
}
```

`bar<42>()` is ambiguous call. This happens even if I use a char, like `bar<'a'>()`. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: How can the compiler tell the difference between a number and a char?

Comment: @Ben huh? `42` has type `int`, and `'a'` has type `char`

Comment: @M.M But the compiler doesnt know that right? Its not written in c++ so there are no strong type definitions, otherwise [this](http://ideone.com/UawQrT) would be an error or warning or something ...

Comment: @Ben the compiler knows what the types of expressions are. No idea what you mean by "Its not written in c++"

Comment: @M.M but conversions between `char` and `int` obviously happen freely as per the example in my comment above, so how can it tell the difference between `'a'` and `97` ? Honest question?  The non-templated example is resolved at run time right, which is the difference?

Comment: @Ben you're not making any sense sorry. `'a'` is a `char`, `47` is an int. Those are different.   Yes, one can be converted to the other but they are still two different things.  Overload resolution happens at compile-time.

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876228/overloaded-non-type-template-is-ambiguous-while-non-templated-function-is-ok)?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I'd say this question is a duplicate of the one you linked, which has an excellent answer from T.C. that clarifies everything.

Answer (score 7):

The standard **N4140** (credit goes to **M.M**) gives this explanation and sample in **14.8.2 Template argument deduction**:

> <sup>9</sup> Except as described above, the use of an invalid value shall not cause type deduction to fail. [*Example:*
>   In the following example 1000 is converted to `signed char` and results in an implementation-defined value
>   as specified in (4.7). In other words, both templates are considered even though 1000, when converted to
>   signed char, results in an implementation-defined value.
>
> ```
> template <int> int f(int);
> template <signed char> int f(int);
> int i1 = f<1>(0);    // ambiguous
> int i2 = f<1000>(0); // ambiguous
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

However, note that in following drafts the rules are changed [because](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1809):

> This is no longer correct, even ignoring the fact that some implementations may be able to represent the value 1000 as a `signed char`: integral and enumeration non-type template arguments are now converted constant expressions (14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype] paragraph 1), and converted constant expressions disallow narrowing conversions (5.20 [expr.const] paragraph 3).

The proposed sample is:

> ```
> template <int> int f(int);
> template <signed char> int f(int);
>
> int i1 = f<1000>(0); // OK
> int i2 = f<1>(0);    // ambiguous; not narrowing
> ```

Comment: In C++14 the line is `int i2 = f<1000>(0); // ambiguous`  (both are ambiguous) , not sure where you are getting "OK" from

Comment: @M.M I mean 14.8.2/9 of 4296. Which version do you use?

Comment: N4140 (same as C++14) . This is why I suggest to say which document you are quoting. "The standard" is ambiguous, and N4296 is not any standard. It's a draft in between C++14 and C++17.

Comment: @M.M Good point, thanks, edited.

Comment: Having said that, it's possible that it was changed for N4296 as the result of a defect report

Comment: This situation is not the same as in my question. You're taking a parameter but in my question I'm overloading (specializing) purely on the template parameters.

Comment: @M.M http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1809

Comment: @user6378568 the parameter is not ambiguous though so I think it's the same.  (But this example doesn't explain the rationale for the `f<1>` case)

Comment: On top of that, `42` fits within the range of `char` and `int`. The example has to do with narrowing.

Comment: @user6378568 I think it is the same. (But it could be better if the standard uses the sample functions without parameters.)

Comment: The examples seem to indicate template expansion relies less on the type of the non-type template arguments and more on the values themselves when creating instantiations.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between how overloads and specializations are chosen. Overload resolution [ranks implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). No conversion is required to convert `42` to `int`, so it is an **Exact Match**, which beats the implicit conversion required for `42` to `char`.

On the other hand, function template specialization "overloading" uses [partial ordering rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial), which uses template argument deduction to determine which is more "specialized" than the other. Without going into too much detail, deduction doesn't fail for either `int` or `char` with a value of `42`, so they're both equally specialized. If you were to use a value outside the range of an signed char, i.e `128`, deduction would fail and the `int` specialization would be chosen.

Comment: the rule about out-of-range deduction failing seems to have been added after C++14 (see discussion under AlexD's answer)

Comment: It'd be great if you could go into more detail about how the partial ordering process works..:)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [website](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), which has a very good examples and explanation, "*function template specializations don't overload*." Which is why you are receiving `call to 'bar' is ambiguous`.