# How partial template specialization chosen?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Please explain me the rules for template specialization selection. I have an example:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = int>
struct S : false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct S<T, float> : true_type{};

cout << boolalpha << S<float>::value;
```

Why the output is `false`? And in general, what happens with default template parameter `typename T2 = int` in specialized classes? Does it introduces some influence?

Comment: I don't see why you would expect anything different here. The `float` in `S<float>` is the *first* type parameter `T1`, not the second `T2`. But the specialization is for if `T2` is `float`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Presumably, the OP is attempting to specify the template parameter of the partial specialization (`T`); not an uncommon beginner mistake.

Comment: My initial thoughts were that id I specify one template parameter, compiler should select specialization, because it prefer specialization over base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Choosing a template specialization happens in five steps:

1. Take the primary template declaration. (`<T1, T2 = int> S`)
2. Fill in user-specified template arguments. (`T1 <- float`)
3. Function templates only: Deduce additional template arguments.
4. Use defaults for remaining template arguments. (`T2 <- int`)
5. Use the partial ordering algorithm (C++14 14.5.6.2) to choose the best-matching specialization. (`<float, int>` does not match `<T, float>`, so ignore the specialization; only possibility left is primary template)

Comment: It's logical! Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for an rough explanation of the partial ordering in step 5, I'd recommend looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17008568/1248889