# How does std::remove_const<T> work internally

Tags: c++, std, type-traits

**Case 1**
The possible implementation of std::remove_const is

```
template< class T > struct remove_const          { typedef T type; };
template< class T > struct remove_const<const T> { typedef T type; };
```

When i use them

```
std::remove_const<int> // use the first version
std::remove_const<const int> // use the second version
```

**Case 2**
If i comment the second version

```
template< class T > struct remove_const          { typedef T type; };
//template< class T > struct remove_const<const T> { typedef T type; };
```

And use them

```
std::remove_const<int> // use the first version
std::remove_const<const int> // use the first version
```

In the Case 1 , **how does compiler decide to choose the second version for** **const int** ?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35652212/1896169

Comment: I think you're asking how partial template specialization works. It's complicated, but this wiki is a decent overview: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization . The short answer is `const int` is a closer match to `const T` than plain-old-`T`, so it is preferred.

Comment: @TravisGockel Thanks for the link. I have read about the Template Specialization. But example I saw, use specialization for completely different type ( for e.g. int, float, short) but not with closely related types ( e.g. int and const int). Thanks for the info

Comment: Of course there is a standard for it. An ISO standard to be exact. While the official publication is proprietary, the last drafts prior to publication are available to the public (and are nearly identical to the finished document).

Comment: On a related note you shouldn't really use `remove_const` in your code. 99 times out of 100, if you are then you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specialization.

The `const T` version is more specialized than the generic version (because if a type match `const T`, match the generic `T` also; `int` match `T` but not `const T`).

The rule is that if a type match two or more versions, the compiler must choose the more specialized one.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* two different versions of a template.  This is a single template (what you call the first version), with a specialization defined (what you call the second version).

So when you use the template it always first finds the definition of the template, and then looks for preexisting specializations and instantiations of the template that match the type signature you are using.  If it finds a specialization (or instantiation) that matches, it uses that.  Only if there is no existing specialization or instantiation does it instatiate the template.

So when you say `remove_const<int>` it matches the template, but does not match the specialization, so it instantiates the template.  `remove_const<const int>` matches the template and also matches the specialization, so it uses the specialization (which is also a template, so needs to be instantiated, but that is secondary).

The thing that makes your "second version" a specialization rather than a new template is the `<`..`>` list after the name `remove_const`.