# is it possible to check if T is a primary template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it somehow possible to check **during compile time** whether `T` is a primary template or a specialization?
Expected usage:

```
template <typename>
struct foo{};

template <>
struct foo<double>{};

static_assert(is_primary_template<foo<int>>::value);
static_assert(!is_primary_template<foo<double>>::value);
```

**It must yield true for a type instantiated from a primary template and false for template specialization.**

I can't think of a way to implement this, rather with some workaround using type tags

```
template <typename T> 
using is_primary_template = std::is_base_of<primary_template, T>;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the primary template of a function specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284153/how-to-determine-the-primary-template-of-a-function-specialization)

Comment: @infinitezero no, that question is about differences in definitions - completelly different question.