# Why does this template function overload resolution depend on the declaration order?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

//                     void foo(int* t ) { std::cout << "variant int* t, non-template\n"; }
template<typename T> void foo(T t    ) { std::cout << "variant T t\n"; }
template<>           void foo(int* t ) { std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; }
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   ) { std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo( new int{1} );
    return 0;
}
```

If the non-template version is uncommented, then it is preferred in the overload resolution, as expected. Let's leave it commented.

Curiously, whether the variant with `T* t` or `int* t` is chosen in overload resolution depends on the order of declaration.

The output is `variant T* t` with the lines

```
template<>           void foo(int* t ) { std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; }
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   ) { std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; }
```

The output is `variant int* t` with the swapped lines

```
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   ) { std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; }
template<>           void foo(int* t ) { std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; }
```

So it seems that the order of declaration matters. But shouldn't the most special specialization be preferred? What rule applies here?

Comment: `int *t` specializes one of those two template functions. Normally it specializes `T *t` , but if it's declared before that, it instead specializes `T t`. This will be easier if you overload instead of specializing.

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to determine the primary template of a function specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284153/how-to-determine-the-primary-template-of-a-function-specialization)

Comment: "When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation." ~ C++ standard

Answer (score 4):

**tldr**

There are two **primary templates** here and only primary templates take part in overload resolution. For the call `foo(new int{1})`, the primary template `#2` is a better match. In the second snippet, the second template `#2` has a specialization which by definition is more specialized than the primary template `#2` and so is used.

---

##### Case 1

Here we consider the case when we have the order as:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T t    )  //#1 primary template
{ 
    std::cout << "variant T t\n"; 
} 
//this specializes the above #1
template<>           void foo(int* t ) 
{ 
    std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; 
}
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   )  //#2 primary template
{ 
    std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; 
}
```

The important thing to note is that:

a) **only primary templates take part in overload resolution**. This means that only `#1` and `#2` take part in overload resolution. This means that for the call `foo( new int{1} )`, the second template `#2` is selected as it is a **better match** than the other.

b) Note that in this case, the second primary template `#2` doesn't have any specialization so the `#2` is used and we get the output as `variant T*`. The specialization that you've provided is for `#1` which can't be used because `#1` is worst match than `#2`.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the declaration order as:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T t    )  //#1 primary template
{ 
    std::cout << "variant T t\n"; 
} 
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   )  //#2 primary template
{ 
    std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; 
}
//this specializes the above #2
template<>           void foo(int* t ) 
{ 
    std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; 
}
```

In this case again **only the primary templates `#1` and `#2` take part in overload resolution**. And the second primary template `#2` is a **better match** than the first `#1`.

But the *difference is that* this time **there exists a specialization** for the selected `#2`. And since a specialization is more specialized than the primary template, that is used and so we get the output as `variant int*`

Answer (score 3):

There are (only) two templates here:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T t    ) { std::cout << "variant T t\n"; }
template<typename T> void foo(T* t   ) { std::cout << "variant T* t\n"; }
```

The line

```
template<>           void foo(int* t ) { std::cout << "variant int* t\n"; }
```

is a specialization of a template, not itself a template.  If it is after the second template it is a specialization of the second template, but if it is between, it specializes the first template.

When you call `foo(int *)` in main, either template can match, but the second one matches better so that is the one that is used.  If (and only if) the specialization is a specialization of that template, it will be used.

Comment: Could one say: once the template with `int*` is declared, it sees whether it is a specialization of one the previous templates, and if yes, it picks the best fit and sticks with that one? My way of thinking was that `pick the parent template` happens when the compiler resolves `foo( int* )` in main.