# overloaded templates resolution

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

```
// g++(5.4)

void func(int * const &) {}
void func(int *) {}

template <typename T> void tfunc(const T &) {}
template <typename T> void tfunc(T *) {}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;

  func(&a);   // ambiguous
  tfunc(&a);  // unambiguous

  return 0;
}
```

According to my another test, `tfunc(&a)` instantiates the first template to `void tfunc(int * const &)` which has the same parameter type as the first nontemplate.

So, why is the first call ambiguous but the second not?

Comment: For the first call the mechanism at play is ordinary value conversion for the argument, for ordinary function overload resolution. Both (non-) conversions are apparently equally good. For the second call the mechanism at play is function template argument deduction. Here one wins, because it's an *exact match*. Sorry that I can't give you a full answer down to the detail level, but this is the direction to look for that answer: that the mechanisms at play are very different, with different rule sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given two function templates that are otherwise equally as good, overload resolution will select the *more specialized* function template, using a procedure commonly known as *partial ordering*. The exact rules are pretty complicated, but essentially it tries to determine if the set of arguments template A can be called with is a (proper) subset of the set of arguments template B can be called with. If so, then A is more specialized than B, and overload resolution will prefer A.

Thus, in your case, `tfunc(const T&)` can be called with ~everything; `tfunc(T*)` can only be called with pointers. The latter is more specialized, and is therefore selected.

If you are interested in the standardese and detailed rules, see [[temp.func.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.func.order) and [[temp.deduct.partial]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.partial).

Comment: The OP claims the *first* template is called, which disagrees with your answer (and is surprising to me).  Is the OP incorrect in this claim?  Did I read the OP wrong?  Or is something strange going on?

Comment: @Yakk: Yep, that OP's claim is wrong. (I didn't notice it in my original comment on the question.)

Comment: @Yakk I don't think it's claiming that the first one *is* called; it's claiming that the first one *can be* called - or, is viable - by deducing `T = int *` ("another test").

Answer (score 2):

There are some special rules in overload resolution for template functions, one of them is :

> F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is **more specialized than** the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/whats-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction) about how to determine which function template is more specialized.

Here, as the second template function is more specialized, there is no ambiguation.

---

```
#include <iostream>
void func(int * const &) {}
void func(int *) {}

template <typename T> void tfunc(const T &) {std::cout << "#1\n";}
template <typename T>void tfunc(T *) {std::cout << "#2\n";}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;

  //func(&a);   // ambiguous
  tfunc(&a);  // unambiguous

  return 0;
}
// output: #2
```

Edit: Though a test in https://ideone.com/C9rF8b , we can see that the second template is chosen, not the first one as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because a const pointer and a non-const pointer (i.e. `T * const` and `T *`) makes no difference if they appear in a function's parameters, and so does passing by value (by copy) and passing by const reference. That's the reason why `f(&a)` is ambiguous.

For the second one, since `&a` is resolved to `int *`, the second template matches better because it's more specialized (it can't accept non-pointer arguments). The first template is more general so it's not used.

If you change the first template function to this it will also be ambiguous:

```
template <typename T>
void tfunc(T * const &) {}
```