# Partial specialization and the need for std::void_t<>

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, partial-specialization

One for the language lawyers....

I'm playing around with SFINAE and TMP, trying to get a deeper understanding.

Consider the following code, a naive implementation of std::is_default_constructible

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void> struct is_default_constructable : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_default_constructable<T, decltype(T()) > : std::true_type {};

class NC { NC(int); };  // Not default constructable

#include <iostream>
int main(int, char **)
{
    std::cout << "int is_default_constructible? " << is_default_constructable<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NC is_default_constructible? " << is_default_constructable<NC>() << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles fine, but doesn't actually work, it returns false for all types.

For the NC case, this is as I'd expect, `T()` is not well-formed so that specialization is discarded due to SFINAE and the primary template (false_type) is used.  But for the `int` case, I'd expect the specialization to be used as `decltype(T())` is valid and equivalent to `T`.

If, based on the actual code in `<type_traits>`, I change the specialization to

```
template <typename T> using wrap = void;
template <typename T> struct is_default_constructable<T, wrap<decltype(T())> > : std::true_type {};
```

(i.e. wrap the second template parameter in a mockup of `std::void_t<>` which forces the second type to be `void`), this works as expected.

Even more curious, variations of this scheme using types other than `void` as the default type in the primary template or `wrap<>` also fail, *unless the two types are the same.*

Can someone explain why the type of `wrap<>` and the second template argument default type need to be the same in order for the specialization to be selected?

(I'm using "g++ -Wall --std=c++17" with g++ version 6.3, but I think this is not compiler-related.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a consequence of SFINAE or partial specialization ordering, but due to the use of default template parameters.  Informally, the reason is that the application of default template parameters happens *before* the search for template definitions, including possible specializations.

So in the above case, the code that says `is_default_constructable<int>` is actually requesting to instantiate a template `is_default_constructable<int, void>` after applying the default second parameter.  Then possible definitions are considered.

The "primary" template definition clearly matches and is included. 
The given partial specialization

```
template <typename T> struct is_default_constructable<T, decltype(T()) > : std::true_type {};
```

is actually defining `is_default_constructable<int, int>` which does not match the requested `is_default_constructable<int, void>` so the specialization is ignored, even if the substitution succeeds.
This leaves the primary definition (inheriting false_type) as the only viable definition so it is chosen.

When the specialization has `wrap<>` (or `std::void_t<>`) to force the second arg to a `void`, the specialization is defining `is_default_constructable<int, void>` which matches the request. This definition (asuming the substitution succeeds, i.e. `T()` is well formed) is more specialized than the primary definition (according to super-complicated rules for ordering specializations), so it is chosen.

As an aside, the above naive implementations probably don't work as expected when T is a reference type or other corner cases, which is a good reason to use the standard library versions of all this. Them standards committee people are way smarter than I am and have already thought of all these things.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51479514/5287373) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688405/5287373) to somewhat-related questions have more detailed information that set me right.

And, yes, I can't spell constructible, assuming that's even a word.  Which is another good reason to use the standard library.