# Function overload resolution with nullptr as argument

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, ambiguous-call

Consider the code below. Although both overloads of `fun` accept pointers, passing `nullptr` to `fun` does not result in any compilation error. Whereas, the very similar function `bun` fails to compile. When I print the the types of the argument `i` using `typeid(i).name()` *(after modifying the code just to get this printed)* I get the same type, simply `int*`. What is the rule that resolves the ambiguity in `fun` case, but fails for `bun`? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int sth;
};

template< class U>
void fun(decltype(U::sth)* i){
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template< class U>
void fun(U* i){
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

void bun(decltype(Foo::sth)* i){
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
}

void bun(Foo* i){
    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
}

int main ( )
{
    fun<Foo>(nullptr);
    // bun(nullptr); --> call of overloaded 'bun(std::nullptr_t)' is ambiguous        
    return 0;          
}
-----------------------
output : 1
```

Comment: I have an inkling feeling now that it has to do with non deduced contexts, but I might be entirely wrong.

Comment: The compiler can prove that the first template is more specialized than the second template, so it will always pick it when a template invocation can match both templates. That's the rule. Maybe if someone can't rattle off a capsule explanation of specialization that applies to this question precisely, I might get to this tomorrow. This is very thick in the weeds, and, unfortunately, I've lost a bookmark to a pretty good article that fully explains this, that I can just shamelessly plagiarize (not).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact, [GCC accepts your code, but Clang does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c53926e71c3de77). So it is not, at first, obvious whether the call is ambiguous.

You ask what rule resolves the ambiguity in the `fun` case; GCC evidently thinks that there is such a rule. I imagine the rule that GCC is applying is the rule [over.match.best]/1.7 that prefers a *more specialized* function template over a less specialized one.

The procedure for determining which function template is more specialized than the other is described in [temp.func.order] and is explained thoroughly in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17008568/481267). However, you will notice that when attempting to apply this procedure to the two overloads of `fun` as in this question, we run into the problem that the unique synthesized type that needs to be substituted for `U` in the first overload would need to have a member named `sth`, and the nature of this member is not specified, and although it may be clear to a human that deduction in the second `fun` overload must succeed regardless of what `sth`'s type is, the compiler may not be able to prove it.

This is [CWG 1157](http://wg21.link/cwg1157). As this issue is still open with no proposed resolution, I have no insight into whether WG21 intends for this overload resolution to succeed or not.