# How overload resolution decides the best between type and substituted type?

Tags: c++, c++20, function-templates-overloading

I have example that works, but I believe it should not

```
template <typename T>
void foo(int n) {
    std::cout << "foo(int)" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "foo(T)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  foo<double>(42.0); // 1
  foo<int>(42);      // 2
}
```

[Live example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sbKd4z)

For (1) everything is ok, exact template match beats standard conversion double -> int

But for (2) resulting instantiation looks equivalent for both overloads, and I expected error in this case

Still both clang 11 and gcc 10.2 agree that best match for (2) is foo(int), so looks like I don't understand something important

Comment: The first overload is more specialized (see “partial ordering”).

Comment: I looked through [temp.func.order] of course but I can not see any evidence why first is more specialized

Comment: Oh, looks like I got it. The idea is in matching first vs second and vice versa. So that we do have <T> void f(T) matched to f(int) but void f(int) not matched to f(T*) for some invented T*....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the partial ordering procedure in template deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/what-is-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction)

Comment: Yes this is close enough, thanks