# Raw int pointer vs vector::iterator<int>

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, function-templates-overloading

I was trying to understand difference between a raw pointer and an vector iterator. However, the following program trips me out. Does template function have priority over non-template function?

Expected: hello! world!
Actual: hello! hello!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename It>
void foo(It begin, It end) {
  cout << "hello! ";
}

void foo(const int* a, const int* b, size_t n=0) {
  cout << "world! ";
}

int main() {
  vector<int> A = {5,6,7,8,9};
  int B[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
      
  foo(A.begin(), A.end());
  foo(B, B+5);

  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Whatever resource you use to learn C++, it has taught you something [very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h),

Comment: Just because you called your template parameter `It` does not impart any specific meaning. It does not have to be an iterator. The overload resolution will match your non-const int pointer.

Comment: Ah, I know it's importing bunch of libraries - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Time for more coffee or more sleep ;)

Comment: @paddy New (or perhaps only cleaner) glasses perhaps... :)

Comment: Even if the vector iterators are plain pointers, the template will have deduced `int*`, which is a much closer match than `const int*`

Comment: @paddy `int *` *is* an iterator, so even with concepts `template<std::input_or_output_iterator It>` would match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general iterators of the class template `std::vector` are not pointers (though in some early versions of compilers they were implemented as pointers).

For the both calls there will be called the template function. The call of the non-template function requires conversion to const (qualification conversion).

The non-template function would be called if the array was declared with the qualifier const like

```
const int B[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

On the other hand, if you will declare the vector with the qualifier const like

```
const vector<int> A = {5,6,7,8,9};
```

nevertheless the template function will be called because there will be used objects of the type `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` that are not pointers to constant objects.

Comment: I changed the signature of the second foo to 
    void foo(int* a, int* b, size_t n=0) {
      cout << "world! ";
    } In that case is the template function ignored?

Comment: @HeeHwang In this case for the array there will be called the non-template function because neither conversion is required.

Answer (score 1):

`iterator` is a set of classes that are used in various containers of the STL. Having this paradigm guarantees that you can use an iterator in template where the container is a template

```
template<typename Container> is_alone(const Container& c) {
    Container::iterator i = c.begin();
    if(i == c.end())  {
        return false;
    }
    ++i;
    return i == c.end();
}
```

This snippet above will work whether Container is a `std::vector`, a `std::unordered_map`, a `std::set`, ...
How the iterators access the members of a container is left implantation-defined.
In concrete terms, a `std::vector<T>::iterator` will almost always be implemented using a pointer, however this is hidden from the user of a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, which only needs to know that iterator can be advanced, and can be accessed with `operator*`.

For you snippet code, the C++ compiler will always target the function with the most specialized argument types that match the concrete argument type you're calling with.
Here it is `int*`, so calling the template by setting `It = int*`, is more specialized than calling the function with `const int*`, so the template is preferred.

Comment: I did an experiment and changing two parameters of the non-template function to int* takes precedence over the template function. How does C++ resolve `specialness`?

Comment: @HeeHwang Using [partial ordering rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/what-is-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction)

Comment: Note that in this case, this is not template specialization, but function overloading.

Comment: @HeeHwang There are tutorials for function template + function overloading out there, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-function-templates-in-c/.

Comment: @Lærne geeksforgeeks is a terrible site to learn C++. Don't recommend that site, it has lots of wrong articles.

Comment: GFG bad; [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116) good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what is happening on case by case basis.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the call:

```
foo(A.begin(), A.end());
```

Here the arguments `A.begin()` and `A.end()` of the call expression are of type `std::vector::iterator` but the parameter `a` and `b` of the nontemplate function are of type `const int*`. Now, since there is no implicit conversion between the argument type `std::vector::iterator` to the parameter type `const int*`, the nontemplate function is **not even viable** for this call.

Thus, the template function can be used with its parameter deduced to `std::vector::iterator`. And hence we get the first `hello!` in the output.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the call:

```
foo(B, B+5);
```

In this case both the arguments are of type `int*`(since array decay to pointer to their first element here).

Now, here there are **two viable candidates**.

*First* candidate is the nontemplate function with parameters `a` and `b` of type `const int*`. But note that for this nontemplate function to be used a *qualification conversion*(from `int*` to `const int*`) is required.

*Second* candidate is the function `foo<int *>(int *, int *)`generated from
the function template where the parameter is deduced to be `int*`.

So we have two candidates. But as discussed above, the first candidate requires a conversion while the second candidate(which is generated from function template) does not require any conversion from argument type to parameter type. Thus, the second candidate is preferred over the first candidate and we get the second `hello!` in the output.

---

##### Sidenote

If you were to change the type of the parameter of the nontemplate function to be `int*`, then the nontemplate function would be preferred over the one generated from the function template and in this case you'll get the `world!` as the output for the call `foo(B, B+4)`.

```
template<typename It> //#1
void foo(It begin, It end) {
  cout << "hello! ";
}
//-------vvv-----vvv----------------------->changed to int* 
void foo(int* a, int* b, size_t n=0) {//#2
  cout << "world! ";
}

int main() {
  vector<int> A = {5,6,7,8,9};
  int B[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
      
  foo(A.begin(), A.end()); //calls #1 
  foo(B, B+4);             //calls #2
 
  cout << endl;
}
```