# How is this template specialization instantiated

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

I was cobbling together some template recursion to construct a simple compile time integer range and ended up with this

```
#include <iostream>
template<int N, bool Enable = true>
struct S{
    static void print(){
        std::cout << N << ", ";
        S<N - 1>::print();
    }
};
template<int N>
struct S<N, N < 0>{
    static void print(){
        std::cout << N << ", ";
        S<N + 1>::print();
    }
};
template<>
struct S<0>{
    static void print(){
        std::cout << "0.\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    S<-5>::print();
    S<5>::print();
}
```

The output is

```
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0.
5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.
```

I expected this to work, but when I look at it I can't explain *why* its working.  I've been perusing the cppreference *Partial template specialization* topic, I think the section on "members of partial specializations" hold some explanation that I'm unable to decipher. [cppinsights just gives me a description of the observed behavior](https://cppinsights.io/s/be38e2d0).

So why is

```
template<int N>
static void S<N, N < 0>::print()
```

preferred over

```
template<int N, bool Enable = true>
static void S<N, Enable>::print()
```

When `N < 0`?  The same is observed when `print` is a non-static member, as I expect it to be.

Comment: Partial ordering ([\[temp.spec.partial.order\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.order)) rules resulting in one specialization being _more specialized_ than the other one.

Comment: [What is the partial ordering procedure in template deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/what-is-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction)

Comment: `template<int N, bool Enable = true> struct S` is a **primary template** while `S<N, N < 0>` is a partial specialization. The partial specialization will be selected if the first template parameter `N` is less than `0`. That is why for `N=-5`, the partial template version is selected while for the `N=5` the primary template is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary template is by-definition less specialised than any specialisations.

When expanding the uses `S<N + 1>` and `S<N - 1>`, `N < 0` is evaluated and that specialisation is applicable if it matches the value `true`, which comes from the default in the primary template.

`N < 0` is only true when N is strictly negative, and that specialisation counts up. Once it reaches `0`, that specialisation isn't applicable, but the `S<0>` one is.

Because the recursive uses don't supply the second template parameter, even if you [supply false explicitly](https://godbolt.org/z/xnMPvb8hc) things sort themselves out.

Comment: "Your two partial specialisations" - Note that OP is actually comparing a partial specialization to a primary template, so we needn't go to partial ordering rules between different partial specializations.

Comment: Thanks, and the godbolt example was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> So why is
>
> ```
> template<int N>
> static void S<N, N < 0>::print()
> ```
>
> preferred over
>
> ```
> template<int N, bool Enable = true>
> static void S<N, Enable>::print()
> ```
>
> When `N < 0`?

Because the former is more specialized. When `N < 0`, the former is a specialization for `Enable == true`, and you pass `true` to `Enable` (implicitly via the default argument), which matches the specialization.

Comment: So when N >= 0 the specialization is no longer a specialization of the primary?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Specializations are specializations(of the primary) irrespective of whether `N>=0` or not.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It is still a specialization, but now for `Enable == false`, which no longer matches your argument.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe There's a variant of this trick where you do `typename = void` instead of a boolean, and then `std::enable_if_t<(N < 0)>`. Then yes, it would no longer be a (valid) specialization for `N >= 0` (would be rejected by SFINAE).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the program can be understood using [partial ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

> When a class or variable(since C++14) template is instantiated, and there are partial specializations available, the **compiler has to decide if the primary template is going to be used or one of its partial specializations**.
>
> - **If only one specialization matches the template arguments, that specialization is used**

(emphasis mine)

`template<int N, bool Enable = true> struct S` is a **primary template** while  `template<int N> struct S<N, N < 0>` is a **partial specialization**. This partial specialization will be used when the first template parameter `N` is less than `0` which is why for `N=-5` the partial specialization is used while for `N=5` the primary template is used.

```
S<-5>::print() //this uses partial specialization S<N, N < 0>
S<5>::print() //this uses the primary template
```